# Help With Embedded BaseFormDoctrine Forms

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have the following code blocks:

```
class MerchantStoreForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->disableCSRFProtection();

    $this->setWidgets(array(
          'brand_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('label'=> 'Store Brand','model'=>'Brand','add_empty'=>'-Select Brand-','method'=>'getName','key_method'=>'getId','order_by'=>array('name','asc'))),
          'newbrand'    => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(array('label' => 'New'),array('value'=>'Y'))
    ));

    $this->setValidators(array(
        'newbrand' => new sfValidatorString(array('required'=>false)),          
        'brand_id'  => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model'=>'Brand'))
    ));

     $brand = new Brand();
    $brand_form = new BrandForm();
    $brand_form->widgetSchema['name']->setAttribute('style','display:none');
    $this->embedForm('brand', $brand_form);

    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('store[%s]');
  }

  public function execute()
  { 
   $form_values = $this->getValues();

    if($form_values['newbrand'])
    {
        $brand_form = $this->getEmbeddedForm('brand');
        $brand_form->save();
        $brand = $brand_form->getObject();
    }
    else
    {
        $brand = doctrine::getTable('Brand')->findOneById($form_values['brand_id']);
    }

    return $brand->getId();
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1) The magic of $brand_form->save() doesn't work for me. I get a 500 Internal Server Error sfValidatorErrorSchema error pointing to the following piece of code in my symfony generated BaseBrandForm.class.php:

```
...
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('brand[%s]');
$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
...
```

This works instead in replacement though:

```
        $brand_form->updateObject($form_values['brand']);
        $brand_form->getObject()->save();
```

Why is this?

2) Why do I get an undefined method error while calling getter method on the object of the BaseFormDoctrine embedded form:
                return $brand->getId();

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sharmil

Answer (score 1):

1) BrandForm throws an exception because it doesn't have any values. Classes that extend `sfFormObject` don't play nicely when embedded directly into non object forms (like `sfForm`).

What is MerchantStoreForm doing? Depending on the situation, it should probably be extending `sfFormObject` or BrandForm should be the top level form. If this isn't possible, you'll have to write add a save method to MerchantStoreForm that calls `updateObject` and `save`. To better understand what's happening, go through the logic that takes place in `sfFormObject` - it's worth knowing especially if you're using embedded forms.

2) No clue here. I would see what $brand is actually an instance of. If it's a record and that record has an id field, there's no reason that shouldn't work.